# How to scrape data from following html using querySelector or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, queryselector

I want to get text from this html using querySelector or jQuery.

```
<td>
   <a href="#" class="verify-address pull-right">
   Verify Address
   </a>
   <div class="verify-address-address-content">
      Tom Heilig<br>
      8642 PEPPER LN<br>
   </div>
   MECHANICSVILLE, VA 22221-4943 US
   <br>
   +1 412-111-1111<br>
   <div class="text-success" style="white-space:normal">
  <span>Address Verified</span>
   </div>
</td>
```

OUTPUT should be like

Tom Heilig

8642 PEPPER LN

MECHANICSVILLE, VA 22221-4943 US

+1 412-111-1111

Can any one please help me out in this?

Comment: Wrap your content inside an div and use document.getElementById('containerElement id').innerText;

Comment: @saravana I think OP doesn't need the content of `span` tags which will be included in the `innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `td`'s inner content is wrapped inside a `div` with id `datarow` like that:

```
<td>
   <div id="datarow">
      ...
   </div>
</td>
```

Then this Jquery code will work like charm:

```
alert(
    $("#datarow").clone()                // Clone the content
                 .find('span').remove()  // Remove all span tags
                 .end()                  // Return to the clone
                 .text()                 // Only text
)
```